# How to get default fonts properties on Android?

Tags: android, text, canvas

I need to draw some text on my Canvas, and I'd really avoid hardcoding some particular text size.

Is there some standard way to find a default text size (and other properties) used in the OS?

So far I found only TextView.setTextAttributes(context, resId) to which I can pass R.android.attr.textAppearance.

But the thing is that I don't want to create a TextView - I just have a Canvas and i want to draw text in it using default font.

Is it possible? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the [`Paint.FontMetrics`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/graphics/Paint.FontMetrics.html) class, and methods like `measureText()` on `Paint`.

Comment: You mean I should use default constructed Paint object and then getFontMetrics() will contain right values? I should try it.